# NameError undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help with including the Answers form if a Question is present inside the messages view. I am getting a `` NameError: undefined local variable or method `question' `` on the line `= form_for(:question, :url => question_answers_path(question)) do |f|`.

If it helps the messages are coming from the Conversations controller.

/messages/_form.html.slim:

```
| if question = @message.question.present?
= form_for(:question, :url => question_answers_path(question)) do |f|
  ul
    li= f.text_area :answer,  placeholder=('Please add your response...') 
    li= f.text_field :recipient_id,  placeholder=('Please add your name...') 
    li= f.submit "Respond"

    | else
    = form_for :message, url: [:reply, conversation] do |f|
        = f.text_area :body, rows: 4, style: 'width: 95%'
        br
        = f.submit "Send Message", class: 'btn btn-primary'
        = submit_tag 'Clear Reply Box', type: :reset, class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

Answers controller:

```
  def new
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    if @question.update_attributes(params[:question])
      redirect_to questions_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Questions controller:

```
   def show
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
      @questions = Question.order("created_at DESC")
      respond_with(@questions)
    end

    def create
      @question = Question.new(params[:question])
      if @question.save
        @message = current_user.send_message(@question.recipient, @question.question, "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}") 
        redirect_to :back, notice: 'Your question was saved successfully. Thanks!'
      else
        render :new, alert: 'Sorry. There was a problem saving your question.'
      end
    end
  end
```

Original form code that works that is inside the "answers" folder (I am trying to get the below code to work in the "messages" folder instead):

```
<%= form_for(:question, :url => question_answers_path(@message.question)) do |f| %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= f.text_area :answer, {:placeholder => 'Please add your response...'}%></li>
        <li><%= f.text_field :recipient_id, {:placeholder => 'Please add your name...'} %></li>
        <li><%= f.submit "Respond" %></li>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
```

Routes:

```
  resources :questions do
    resources :answers, only: [:new, :create]
  end
```

Comment: try @question instead of just saying "question" in your form

Answer (score 0):

You should try to update code like:

```
- question = @message.question # will avoid making multiple calls to db for same record
| if question.present?
= form_for(:question, :url => question_answers_path(question)) do |f|
```

Comment: Thanks. However I'm still trying to get over the NameError, but I will keep that modification in mind for the if statement.

Comment: @CorneliusWilson Did you try un-confusening the `if` statement and doing it on two lines?

Comment: @RAJ... It gives ``undefined method `question' for nil:NilClass``. The page works if I do `@question` but that will gives routing error ``No route matches [POST] "/questions/answers"``

Comment: @CorneliusWilson show me your `messages_controller.rb`

Comment: @RAJ... messages controller added

Comment: @CorneliusWilson Something fishy here, `@message` is new instance, so you can't call `.question` on that till it got saved. What is you use case? How you will make `question` available in `messages/_form`?

Comment: I used to have `@question.message = @message` before the Question was saved in the questions controller. That was prior to using the Mailboxer gem. So I have started from scratch and got rid of that part. With the current code I can visit `/questions/id` and answer the question from the form with zero issues. I'm just trying to move that form inside the messages view. That form uses `<%= form_for(:question, :url => question_answers_path(@message.question)) do |f| %>`

Comment: If you want `@question.message = @message` so you need to create `@message` first. Create a msg record in 'messages/_form' instead of getting answer from user here. Now when you will create `question`, you will have `message`

Comment: @RAJ...I don't follow. I have it setup already so when a Question is created it creates a message. I was using `@question.message = @message` previously because I had a completely different setup. That code was in place when I built inbox messaging from scratch. It is no longer needed now that I am using the Mailboxer gem. To answer a question works in a different view, no form errors at all. No matter what code I change I cannot get the form to submit to the Questions table from inside the conversations view. I think I am confusing myself and in return confusing you too lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60190/discussion-between-raj-and-cornelius-wilson).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing `question` into the path helper, but it is undefined. You should be using `@message.question`:

```
question_answers_path(@message.question)
```

Comment: I tried that prior to posting here and it gave the same error. I just double check to reconfirm. My original code prior to switching to SLIM and I was working out of a different views folder was `<%= form_for(:question, :url => question_answers_path(@message.question)) do |f| %>` and that code still works on my app (just not in my new view).